# grep a specific string and replace the file with sed

Tags: bash, sed, grep

I need some solution to replace some string. 
I Have a "file" with this on the content:

> 23674, ICMP ping, OK, 1, 2016-08-25 17:11:02
>   23686, Ping, OK, 1, 2016-08-25 16:05:04
>   23689, SSH Service, OK, 1, 2016-08-25 16:05:49
>   23693, System Free Space, OK, 97.9560, 2016-08-25 16:06:49
>   23713, System Free Space, OK, 88.0078, 2016-09-20 18:02:22
>   23745, C:\ Free, OK, 63.2227, 2016-09-21 10:57:03

I used this code to take "Free" value on it like this:

```
 grep Free file.txt |grep OK | cut -d K -f 2 |cut -d , -f 2 |cut -d . -f 1
```

Then i got this result:

> 97
>   88
>   63

I need to insert "%" into the result using this code:

```
 grep Free rs.txt |grep OK | cut -d K -f 2 |cut -d , -f 2 |cut -d . -f 1 |sed 's/$/%/g'
```

The result like this:

> 97%
>   88%
>   63%

My question is, how to replace the value on the file for example "97.9560" with new result "97%" etc.
Kindly give me an advice.
Thanks

Comment: I presume that rounding the floating value up or down is not important?

Comment: @l'L'l yes i rounding the float not important for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To replace the value in the file:

```
sed -E -i.bak 's/(Free.*OK,[^.]*)[.][^,]*/\1%/' file.txt
```

Example:

```
$ sed -E -i.bak 's/(Free.*OK,[^.]*)[.][^,]*/\1%/' file.txt
$ cat file.txt
23674, ICMP ping, OK, 1, 2016-08-25 17:11:02
23686, Ping, OK, 1, 2016-08-25 16:05:04
23689, SSH Service, OK, 1, 2016-08-25 16:05:49
23693, System Free Space, OK, 97%, 2016-08-25 16:06:49
23713, System Free Space, OK, 88%, 2016-09-20 18:02:22
23745, C:\ Free, OK, 63%, 2016-09-21 10:57:03
```

#### How it works

- `-E`

  This tells sed to use *extended regular expressions*.  This reduces the number of backslashes that we need.
- `-i.bak`

  This tells to change the file in-place, leaving a back-up file.
- `s/(Free.*OK,[^.]*)[.][^,]*/\1%/`

  This tells sed to make the substitution that you need.  In this case, sed looks for text matching the regex `(Free.*OK,[^.]*)[.][^,]*`.  This matches `Free` followed by `OK,` followed by anything except a period, followed by a period, followed by anything except a comma.  The parentheses cause everything from `Free` to the last character before the period to be saved in group 1.

  The text that was matched is replace by `\1%` which means the text belonging to group 1, `\1`, followed by a percent sign, `%`.

Comment: "*This reduces the number of backslashes that we need.*" -- I do not see anything in your RE that requires extended RE; nor do I see anything that would require additional back-slashes if it is omitted.  Also, I'd replace `[.]` with `\.`

Comment: @Sundeep -- Thank you for clarifying that.
John1024 -- Good answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help and explanation @John1024 great answer

Answer (score 1):

Here is `awk` version solution:

```
awk -v OFS=, -F, '/Free.*OK/ {split($4,a,"."); $4=a[1]"%"}1' infile
23674, ICMP ping, OK, 1, 2016-08-25 17:11:02
23686, Ping, OK, 1, 2016-08-25 16:05:04
23689, SSH Service, OK, 1, 2016-08-25 16:05:49
23693, System Free Space, OK, 97%, 2016-08-25 16:06:49
23713, System Free Space, OK, 88%, 2016-09-20 18:02:22
23745, C:\ Free, OK, 63%, 2016-09-21 10:57:03
```

Explanation :

this `awk` command will take actions on only those lines which contains `Free` followed by `OK`. As this file is a `csv` file, get the 4th field and split into two parts separated by `.` . print the part which is of interest after appending `%` sign to it.

`sed` is best suited for find and replace tasks as it support in-place replacement. However it can be achieved through `awk` using following way :

```
awk -v OFS=, -F, '/Free.*OK/ {split($4,a,"."); $4=a[1]"%"}1' infile > infile.tmp && mv infile.tmp infile
```

Comment: Well done; we wrote the same script at the same time.  I slightly prefer `awk -F, '/System Free Space/ {split($4, a, /[.]/); $4 = a[1] "%"} {print}'` because OFS isn't needed, and IMO ending with `1` to indicate printing is obscure.    @dongk: awk is your friend.  Whenever you find yourself with a pipeline of cut & sed, it's a safe bet awk will be briefer and clearer.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of `perl` solution

```
$ perl -pe 's/OK,\s*\d+\K\.\d+/%/ if /Free/' ip.txt
23674, ICMP ping, OK, 1, 2016-08-25 17:11:02
23686, Ping, OK, 1, 2016-08-25 16:05:04
23689, SSH Service, OK, 1, 2016-08-25 16:05:49
23693, System Free Space, OK, 97%, 2016-08-25 16:06:49
23713, System Free Space, OK, 88%, 2016-09-20 18:02:22
23745, C:\ Free, OK, 63%, 2016-09-21 10:57:03
```

- `OK,\s*\d+\K` positive lookbehind, `OK,` followed by zero or more spaces and one or more digits
- `\.\d+` dot followed by one or more digits
- replacement text is `%`, applied only when input line contains `Free`

Another way is to split input line on `,` and change 4th field

```
perl -F, -le '$F[3] =~ s/\.\d+/%/ if /Free/; print join",", @F' ip.txt
```

If result is as expected, changes can be done inplace with

`perl -i` no backup

or

`perl -i.bkp` with backup